# Canada PR with Job offer

Tags: canada, express-entry, pr

Hi all fortunately I got an invite to apply for PR all thanks to additional points I was able to secure post job offer. I have applied for PR and hopefully within few months I will be able to move.

**Question** While waiting for the invite I was able to get another job offer, and I am more inclined to join them. Is this allowed?
Are there any legal obligations on me to work only for the company whose offer I used for my PR processing?

Although I do find obliged and thankful to companyA but they haven't technically sponsored my visa, I paid for it and arranged for all documentation and stuff by my own.

Answer (score 1):

As a Canadian Permanent Resident you are not tied to any company in terms of work authorization. You are free to work for any employer in Canada (it's a bit tricky if you want to settle in Quebec and your application is via the Federal Process but possible).

You are under no contractual obligation to join the first employer, after your application is approved and you move to Canada to become a PR you are free to join the second employer or another employer as a matter of fact.

The one thing I will advise while your application is processing is to either update it by attaching the second job offer or not decline the first one. Once it's processed and you're closer to moving you can let your potential suitors know of your choice.